# Vaadin 23.3.15 and Vaadin 24.+ PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, vaadin, pom.xml

Current error when trying to install/build project:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Let me start by saying, I have looked through all the other StackOverFlow questions that have been posted, like:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

,

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example.application:mytodo:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\my-todo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example.application:mytodo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.b
oot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 from/to Vaadin Directory (https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons): transfer failed for https://
maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.0.pom and 'paren
t.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 18, column 13: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBui
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Absolutely nothing works! I tried the same vaadin project on my Mac machine and my other windows machine and it worked with no configurations.
As well as my colleagues that are in-person are able to start this project with no problem (I am remote, it should not matter, because another colleague that is remote was able to build it and it worked).
I tried disabling my VPN that they provide me from work, no luck.

My question now is: is it possible that there is some problem with my laptop config, or it might be some proxy issue, or connection issue.
Hypothesis 1: My work has installed something on my laptop that prevents the access from where the vaadin dependencies are downloaded.

I have these issue displayed now on my my-todo app provided by Vaadin starter tutorial: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/guide/quick-start:

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'.xml(cvc-elt.1.a)
```

```
Error while downloading 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' to '%HOME%\.lemminx\cache\http\maven.apache.org\xsd\maven-4.0.0.xsd' : '[sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException] unable to find valid certification path to requested target'
```

and lastly:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example.application:mytodo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 (absent): org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 failed to transfer from https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of Vaadin Directory has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 from/to Vaadin Directory (https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

Here's my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/ -->
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytodo</artifactId>
    <name>mytodo</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.1.2</vaadin.version>
        <selenium.version>4.10.0</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5600</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Java Version: jdk-17.0.2-windows

Vaadin: 24+, I also noticed this did not work on Vaadin 23.3.15 as well.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or something I might be able to provide to help you answer this question.

Comment: Assuming you had no problems with e.g. the spring deps: If you have problems with the CAs for maven.vaadin.com, you could try to comment out the repo in your pom. Unless you need something from the directory (the searchable addons from their page are served from there).

Comment: Ok, after some digging and changing dependencies, it seems like I am getting this issue because of springframework boot plugin, do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: If you can not download deps from the internet of things that get downloaded by others in the 10 thousands (vaadin) or most likely millions (spring) per month, it's safe to assume, that the problem is on your end. If you get CA related errors, the chains on your box might be borked or you are using a proxy (or should use one and don't). I close voted now since it seems clearly a network windows problem.